# How to build a palm coupling to compressed air coupling adapter?

Tags: brakes, truck

Trucks use yellow and red coded ISO 1728 "palm couplings" for connecting the air supply and braking compressed air lines from the towing vehicle to a trailer.

I want to build an adapter from the compressed air supply palm coupling (red lid) to a European standard compressed air coupling (7.2 mm nominal inner diameter). This is to power a tire filler or compressed air tools with the truck when I need this on the go.

I'm not sure about which parts will fit together (thread size etc.). Suggestions?

Comment: Just for amusement, my truck driving Father would call the palm couplings *Glad Hands* because of the way it looks like two of them are shaking each other's hands ... kinda funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ISO 1728 document](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=44103) is not public, but I think that it does not specify threads in the palm couplings. It will be different between regions.

For Europe, the palm couplings use either a M16×1.5 or M22×1.5 female thread ([example](http://www.phillipsind.com/product/628.html), [example](http://www.dagefoerde-gmbh.de/shop/?page=gruppe&path=/00000235/00000296)).

Compressed air couplings with a European standard industrial profile of the plugs and a M16×1.5 male thread are available. For example:

- Parker RECTUS Series 26KA [part no. 26KAAD16MPX](http://www.rectus.de/products/qcde_products/low_pressure/brasssteel/single_shut_off/26ka/) for standard brass material ([prices](http://www.mercateo.com/p/1818H-26KAAD16MPX%282d%29PK/Parker_26KAAD16MPX.html))
- Parker RECTUS Series 26KA [part no. 26KAAD16MPN](http://www.rectus.de/products/qcde_products/low_pressure/brasssteel/single_shut_off/26ka/) for nickel-plated brass material ([prices](http://www.mercateo.com/p/1818H-26KAAD16MPN%282d%29PK/Parker_26KAAD16MPN.html))
- ewo 308 series [part no. 308.816](http://ewo-stuttgart.com/ewo761/index.html#127/z) for brass material

You can simply screw them together after winding a good amount of teflon sealing tape around the male thread. Some sellers (e.g. on eBay Germany) also sell these adapters pre-built.